# How to solve Target class [App\Enums\Category] does not exist. for enum declartion and using in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

First, I have seen similar questions but none of them solved my issue.
I have define an enum as laravel 9 documents.
[implicit-enum-binding](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#implicit-enum-binding)

app/Enums/Category.php

```
<?php
  namespace App\Enums;
  enum Category: string
 {
   case Fruits = 'fruits';
   case People = 'people';
 }
```

routes/web.php

```
  use App\Enums\Category;
  use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
  Route::get('/categories/{category}', function (Category $category) {
   return $category->value;
   });
```

url: http://127.0.0.1:8000/categories/people
error:
Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException
Target class [App\Enums\Category] does not exist.

Comment: What is your php version? Enums need php 8.1.0 or higher.

Comment: php 8.1.5 , I think the class file did not get include in web.php dd( class_exists("Category")); returns false @Anisur Rahman

Answer (score 0):

I reinstalled composer with php version 8.1.6. It works properly!